# how can I see the value of a trigger variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

is there any way see the variables values of a trigger when it is running?
I have the following trigger and it runs fine but it doesn' do the update.

```
delimiter //
create trigger TR_TableA
after insert on TableA
for each row
begin

    set @id = 10;

    update TableB l set stock = stock - new.q
    where (l.id) = (@id);
end;
//
```

Somehow the variable new.q doesn't have a value, i checked the value of the variable q in TableA and it does have the value I have inserted.

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why `id` is set through a session variable? Can you show table schemas and some sample data?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the core problem but you miss separator `;` after `set @id = 10` : it should look like `set @id = 10;`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as posted your trigger doesn't make much sense.

> *is there any way see the variables values of a trigger when it is running?*

Now the only way to see the values of a row being inserted/updated is to insert these values into another table that you may create temporarily for debugging purposes. For example

```sql
CREATE TABLE debug_trigger 
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  stamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  value VARCHAR(255)
);
```

And then in your trigger

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TR_TableA
AFTER INSERT ON TableA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- save values for later examination 
    INSERT INTO debug_trigger(value) VALUES (NEW.q);

    -- rest of logic of your trigger
    -- ...
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Once you've done with debugging drop `debug_trigger` table and remove insert statement from the trigger.

Comment: I have created the debug table as you said and I have the values, but the update still doesn't run if I use new.qOrdered but if I use a simple number, (10, for example), the update does run.

Table: debug_trigger
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
qOrdered int(11) 
qSold int(11) 
stamp timestamp

Comment: @Martin Like I said in comments you need to provide table schemas and some (couple of rows) sample data. Also you didn't answer why a session variable `@id` is used?